# Require user to choose 'boy' or 'girl'

Tags: javascript, prompt

I am trying to get my user to respond to the question "are you a boy or a girl?" with one of those two choices and force them to choose one or the other.

I think I am heading in the right direction but whenever i run my code, it hiccups if choosing the second option.

What am i doing wrong?

```
var gender = prompt("Are you a boy or a girl?").toLowerCase();
while (gender !== ("boy" || "girl")) {
    gender = prompt("Please only respond with boy or girl. Now, are you a boy or a girl?");
}
```

Comment: incorect syntax right? `gender !=` is correct with single `=`

Comment: "boy" || "girl" is "boy"

Comment: Better you use confirm("Are you a boy?"). If true then boy and if false than girl. So it will avoid to receive other value

Comment: If I may, a closure may help you here. `var gender = (function() {...})();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper condition would be

```
while (gender !== 'boy' && gender !== 'girl'){
```

That's because `("boy" || "girl")` will always end up as "boy", therefore the `while` will look like `while(gender !== 'boy')`. The `||` in this case is called a "default" operator, a clever use of the logical OR . If the value on the left side is truthy, it will use the left side value. Otherwise, it will evaluate (hence "default") the right side.

Comment: Thanks man, i cant believe that went right past me. i need a break i think.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like

```
var gender = prompt("Are you a boy or a girl?").toLowerCase();

while (["boy", "girl"].indexOf(gender) == -1) {
  gender = prompt("Please only respond with boy or girl. Now, are you a boy or a girl?");
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Personally, I do tildes on `indexOf`, like `!~["boy", "girl"].indexOf(gender)`

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer can't say I have seen that before. I like!